# Giving relations an order to sort by

Tags: django, django-orm

Given the following Django models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Beacon(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    major = models.PostiveIntegerField(max_value=65536)
    minor = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_value=65536)
```

The `Beacon` model is a bluetooth beacon relationship to the room.

I want to select all Rooms that match a given `uuid, major, minor` combination.

The catch is, that I want to order the rooms by the beacon that is nearest to me. Because of this, I need to be able to assign a value to each beacon dynamically, and then sort by it.

Is this possible with the Django ORM?  In Django 1.8?

**NOTE** - I will know the ordering of the beacons beforehand, I will be using the order they are passed in the query string.  So the first beacon (uuid, major, minor) passed should match the first room that is returned by the Room QuerySet

I am envisioning something like this, though I know this won't work:

```
beacon_order = [
    beacon1 = 1,
    beacon0 = 2,
    beacon3 = 3,
]

queryset = Room.objects.annotate(beacon_order=beacon_order).\
               order_by('beacon_order')
```

Comment: Probably yes by annotating. But how would you define *nearest* here? Where is the "position" stored in the database?

Comment: It will be determined by the order of parameters that are passed to the function. So I will know the nearest one by the time I make the query, I just don't know how to tell the ORM the order

Comment: Will your beacon_order be an ordered list, or a dictionary with key-value pairs? The way you have the list right now is not valid Python syntax so I'm trying to figure out what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: `beacon_order` can be whatever it needs to be to make the annotation work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Q, When

beacons = request.query_params.getlist('beacon[]')
query = Q()
order = []

for pos, beacon in enumerate(beacons):
    uuid, major, minor = beacon.split(':')

    query |= Q(
        beacon__uuid=uuid,
        beacon__major=major,
        beacon__minor=minor,
        )

    order.append(When(
        beacon__uuid=uuid,
        beacon__major=major,
        beacon__minor=minor,
        then=pos,
        ))

rooms = Room.objects.filter(query).order_by(Case(*order))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the order of the beacons, there's no need to sort within the QuerySet itself. Take an ordered list called `beacon_list`, which contains the beacons' primary keys in order, e.g. the item at index 0 is the closest beacon's primary key, the item at index 1 is the second closest beacon's PK, etc. Then use a list comprehension:

```
ordered_rooms = [Room.objects.get(pk=x) for x in beacon_list]
```

You don't have to use the PK either, you can use anything which identifies the given object in the database, e.g. the `name` field.

Comment: This is very non-optimal. If I was passed 500 beacons your method would make 500 queries. With annotation, you can do it all in one query

Comment: @synic Annotation and order_by are also not cheap operations. You may want to actually try comparing performance to see just how much of an advantage there is to doing it that way.

Comment: Also, it is impossible to annotate over all model instances with reference to something in your Python code. Annotations can only be made with simple values (e.g. a constant), a reference to a field on the same model, or an aggregate expression (e.g. arithmetic) using one or more of the previous two categories. You'd have to filter for each object, then annotate it, and then sort all of it. That is unlikely to have superior performance to the method I suggest here.